# Laravel/Xampp loading old files

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laravel-blade

I am building a website and I am using Laravel along with Xampp for developing on localhost.
I have encountered a problem that I really cannot get my head around.

I am editing my files for my Laravel project, yet still the old content is showing.

For example, I use this code to separate parts of the page:

```
<div class="container">
    @include('layout.banner')
    <div class="row">
        @include('layout.left')
        @yield('content')
        @include('layout.right')
    </div>
</div>
```

And lets say I change the file right.blade.php to completely blank and save it. The old file is still being used and absolutely nothing changes on the site.

I have:
cleared my cache + sessions and cookies multiple times. 
Checked the files it is using.
Restarted the local server.

What is possibly happening?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Deleted contents of app/storage/views